# React Router negate path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using the nested routing functionality of `react-router-dom` v4 and there is one use case that I haven't found a solution for.

I have two `Route`s at the root component.

One for almost the entirety of the site and the other for the account section.

I was hoping to be able to do something like... 

`<Route path="/^(account)" ... />`

... or something similar, but I so far have been unable to get that working. Is there a mechanism for this?

EDIT Based on Comment:

The `BrowserRouter` component has two defined `Route`s.

```
/* 
 * Would serve as the root route for all pages that aren't under account. 
 * i.e.
 * /
 * /about
 * /some-section
 */
<Route path="/^(account)" component={SiteLayout} />

/*
 * The other would respond on...
 * /account
 * /account/forgot
 * etc.
 */
<Route path="/account" component={Account} />
```

Hopefully that demonstrates what I'm looking for a bit more clearly.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what each route's urls might look like?

Comment: @JordanBonitatis I've added some information that hopefully address your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you could just use a catch all for all other routes?

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
      <Route component={NotAccount} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: I hadn't discovered the `Switch` yet!